# Exported CSV file is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this code which export data from GridView to csv. It works with other sites but not on this current one I've been developing.

The GridView is binded with DataTable in code behind. Following is the event that binds the fetch and bind the data to GridView.

```
    private void bindGridView()
    {
        //Fetching data from DB goes here

        myTable.Columns.Add("type", typeof(int));
        myTable.Columns.Add("rate", typeof(int));

        foreach (DataRow rows in myTable.Rows)
        {
            if (rows["dst"].ToString() == "1875")
            {
                rows["type"] = 1;
                rows["rate"] = 500;
                rows.AcceptChanges();
            }
            else if (rows["dst"].ToString() == "1876")
            {
                rows["type"] = 0;
                rows["rate"] = 30;
                rows.AcceptChanges();
            }
        }

        gridViewData.DataSource = myTable;
        gridViewData.AllowPaging = true;
        gridViewData.PageSize = 10;
        gridViewData.DataBind();
    }
```

Following is the button click event to export data from GridView

```
    protected void btnExportCDR_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (gridViewData.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            lblStatus.Text = "Data is empty. Can not export CDR. Please check your filtering dates.";
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=CDRMMCC_" + System.DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + ".csv");
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.ContentType = "application/text";


            bindGridView();
            gridViewData.AllowPaging = false;



            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            //I did a trace here, gridViewData.Columns.Count is 0. That's why it got skipped, I think.
            for (int k = 0; k < gridViewData.Columns.Count; k++)
            {
                sb.Append(gridViewData.Columns[k].HeaderText + ",");

            }
            sb.Append("\r\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < gridViewData.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < gridViewData.Columns.Count; k++)
                {
                    sb.Append(gridViewData.Rows[i].Cells[k].Text + ",");

                }
                sb.Append("\r\n");
            }
            Response.Output.Write(sb.ToString());
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
    }
```

Please advice.

Comment: Add a breakpoint and step through your code. Does myTable actually have any rows?

Comment: @Kadajski Yes. It has 10 rows. I did the breakpoint, and, For loop for columns was skipped but not for Rows.

Comment: Export from myTable instead of the gridView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `AutoGenerateColumns` property of the `GridView` set to `true` the `Columns` collection will be empty. The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogeneratecolumns.aspx) documentation for this property says:

**"Automatically generated bound column fields are not added to the Columns collection".**

This is the reason your `Columns` collection is empty. As Henk Holterman pointed out use your `DataTable` directly to generate your CSV file.

An alternative approach would be to set the `AutoGenerateColumns` property to `false` and define the Columns explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Hans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893065/hans) answer, you can use `RenderControl` of the GridView which reduces your work.

```
StringWriter strWriter = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(strWriter);

MyGridView.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
Response.Write(strWriter.ToString());
```